# Adjusting Intervals Depending on Time and Priority

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, optimization, time-complexity

## Description

Imagine that you're working at a car wash and your task is to manage the order of which cars that should be washed first. Each car will have two numbers:

1. A priority value between 1-100.
2. An arrival value between 0-100000.

The arrival value describes the time in minutes when the car arrived at the queue, it takes exactly 5 minutes to wash one car, and only 1 car can be washed at the same time.

You'll not follow the order in the queue, instead you'll always choose the car in the queue with the lowest priority. If the washing team isn't busy, you'll pick the car with the lowest priority. As soon as the washing team is ready, you'll pick the next car with the lowest priority.

Now we want to write a program that takes a list of all cars and prints the order (the cars priority value) that the cars should have been picked in.

The input will look like this:

```
c
{ (a,b) , (a,b) , (a,b) }
```

Where `a` is the priority value, `b` is the arrival value and `c` is the amount of cars. The list will always be sorted in ascending order for the value b, and the first `b` will always be 0.

For example, if the input looks like this:

```
4
{ (5,0) , (3,0) , (2,3) , (1,4) }
```

The output should look like this:

```
3
1
2
5
```

## Solution

What I currently do is to sort the priority values with bucket sort (1 to 100), and then loop through all buckets and pick the first car that satisfies the arrival condition `(arrival <= time)` each time until all buckets are empty. Each time I pick a car, I also increase a variable `time` by 5, to keep track of which cars that can be chosen in the next turn. I also keep track of the lowest arrival value to come, and assign `time` to that value if no cars where found, so that the loop doesn't get stuck if the difference in arrival time is greater than 5.

## Question

If we call the amount of cars `C` and the amount of buckets are 100 (because of index 1 to 100), the above mentioned solution runs in `O(C + 100C)` in the worst case. If I run this in C++ and set `C` to 20000 it results in a running time of around 10-15ms.

So, my question is if it's possible to optimize this further so that we get a solution that has a better time complexity, for instance `O(C)` or atleast `O(50C)`? The goal is to get a running time of 0-4ms.

---

## Suggestions

**Priority Queue:**
Unfortunately this implementation still requires 10-15ms to process 20000 cars.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    unsigned int carCount;
    scanf("%d", &carCount);

    priority_queue<unsigned int, vector<unsigned int>, greater<unsigned int>> q;

    unsigned int readCount  = 0;
    unsigned int printCount = 0;
    unsigned int priority   = 0;
    unsigned int arrival    = 0;
    unsigned int time       = 0;

    scanf("%d %d", &priority, &arrival);

    while (printCount != carCount)
    {
        while (readCount != carCount)
        {
            if (arrival <= time)
            {
                q.push(priority);
                ++readCount;
                if (readCount != carCount) scanf("%d %d", &priority, &arrival);
                continue;
            }

            break;
        }

        if (q.empty())
        {
            time = time < arrival ? arrival : time;
            continue;
        }

        printf("%d ", q.top());
        q.pop();
        ++printCount;
        time += 5;
    }

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

**Taking advantage of cars being already sorted:**
Unfortunately this implementation still requires 10-15ms to process 20000 cars.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    unsigned int carCount;
    scanf("%d", &carCount);

    unsigned int buckets[101];
    memset(buckets, 0, sizeof(unsigned int) * 101);

    unsigned int readCount  = 0;
    unsigned int printCount = 0;
    unsigned int priority   = 0;
    unsigned int arrival    = 0;
    unsigned int time       = 0;

    scanf("%d %d", &priority, &arrival);

    while (printCount != carCount)
    {
        while (readCount != carCount)
        {
            if (arrival <= time)
            {
                ++buckets[priority];
                ++readCount;
                if (readCount != carCount) scanf("%d %d", &priority, &arrival);
                continue;
            }

            break;
        }

        unsigned int i;

        for (i = 1; i != 101; ++i)
        {
            if (buckets[i] != 0)
            {
                printf("%d ", i);
                --buckets[i];
                ++printCount;
                time += 5;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (i == 101)
        {
            time = time < arrival ? arrival : time;
        }
    }

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `O(C + 100C) == O(C) == O(50C)`. You don't seem to quite understand the big-O notation, no offense intended.

Comment: Yes, I know that all 3 are classed as linear time complexity, but I wrote it that way to better explain what I'm trying to acheive. Even if O(C) and O(100C) is classed as linear, O(C) will run quicker.

Comment: Seems like you could do this with a simple [priority queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue), like the one in the C++ standard library: `std::priority_queue`. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue

Comment: @JimMischel Interesting idea, I didn't think about the priority queue. In the link you provided it says that the priority queue takes logarithmic time to push and pop, so the time complexity would be `2c*log(c)` if I'm not mistaken. I gave it a try and implemented it, but unfortunately it still takes 10-15 ms to process 20000 cars. I updated the question if you'd like to see the code.

Comment: It would be interesting to know how you're doing your timings. In particular, are the input (`scanf`) and output (`printf`) statements included in your timings? I suspect that majority of your time is spent on I/O. Can you pre-load the items into an array, thereby eliminating the time taken by `scanf` in the loop? And eliminate the `printf` statements? That will tell  us what the actual processing time is.

Comment: @JimMischel I'm sending in the code to an online judging system, pretty much like TopCoder, CodeChef etc. So it's not me that measure the runtime, but the entire program is measured, including `scanf` and `printf`. And unfortunetely I can't pre-load the input data since the testcases are hidden and sent to my program via stdin. Although, should really `scanf` and `printf` take so much time for only 60001 integers in total? Is there anyway I can optimize `scanf` and `printf`?

Comment: I/O is expensive. It wouldn't surprise me to discover that it takes 10 to 15 ms just for the I/O. It'd be simple enough to measure. Just create a sample data file that has a count and 20,000 pairs of integers. Then pipe that file to a program that reads each line and outputs the priority value. Timing that program will tell you how long the I/O takes.

Comment: @JimMischel I measured the runtime manually and it seems that the entire program takes 9ms to run, and when only doing the input and output stuff, it takes 7ms to run. So I guess it's not possible to get below 5ms, unless it's possible to optimize scanf and printf?

Comment: By the way, both of your examples above are essentially the same. The only difference is in your priority queue implementation. In the second, your buckets are the priority queue.

Comment: Optimizing `scanf` and `printf` would not be a fruitful exercise.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you might not be making good use of an important stated feature of the input data, namely that the cars are already sorted by time of arrival.

This allows you to **perform your bucket sort as you go**.

Allocate your 100 buckets and your time variable, as you already have.  But, instead of bucket sorting all cars, bucket sort only the cars that have arrived.  Since the cars are already sorted by time of arrival, this is efficient.  Simply check to see if the first car in the array has arrived (by comparing to your current time value) and, if so, throw it into the appropriate priority bucket (and "remove" it from the array).  Repeat until the first car in the array has not yet arrived.  At this point, your buckets contain only the cars that have arrived.  So, iterate through your priority buckets, starting with the lowest, and grab the first car you find, output it, and remove it from its bucket.  Increment your time value.  Repeat until you run out of cars.

A note about "removing" a car from the list... there is no need to shuffle memory around by actually removing the car from the array.  Instead, you can simply keep a car counter variable that always points to the first unprocessed car in the array.  Since the input data is never destroyed or moved around, this also allows your buckets to contain nothing but indexes (or pointers, if you prefer) to the input array, rather than copies of the cars themselves.

By the bye, another approach would be to skip the buckets altogether, and replace them with a dynamic list (or vector) of cars that have arrived.  As each car arrives, you would need to find its place in the list by priority.

Either way, the main idea is: at a given point in time, only concern yourself with cars that have already arrived.

Comment: Rather than replace the buckets with a dynamic list or vector, replace them with a [priority queue](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue).

Comment: @JamesDroscha Very good point about the cars being already sorted. Also, since I'll just push the same numbers in each bucket, I thought that I might just change the queues to a simple fixed size integer array where each index will represent the amount of numbers that are stored in that bucket. Then I just iterate through this array from 1 to the first non-zero value and simulate a pop by subtracting the value by 1. Unfortunately, this implementation still takes 10-15ms to process 20000 cars. I updated the question if you'd like to see the code.

Comment: @fighting_falcon93 The only other micro-optimization I can think of within this approach is to add a variable to keep track of which bucket is your lowest-priority non-empty bucket, to prevent iterating over all the zeroes each car wash.  But you would still need to iterate over the zeroes when "popping" the last car in a bucket.  You would probably save only a few thousand operations, so I doubt it would make a measurable difference.  For a significant time savings, I think you will need a new approach.